# Scrapy CrawlSpider and LinkExtractor rules to follow all links on a page matching a /path/?

Tags: python, scrapy

i want to follow all of the links on the page https://whitney.org/exhibitions/2012-biennial containing /2012-biennial/

i tried

`class SpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "whit"
    start_urls = ['https://whitney.org/exhibitions/2012-biennial']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='2012-biennial/.*'), callback='parse', follow=True)]`

and it just parses the start url.  there are a bunch of links like /2012-biennial/some-artist that i want to follow and parse.  i checked here on stack overflow a bunch and I can't figure out what I'm getting wrong, it seems like the simplest thing.  thanks

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the HTML from the page containing one of the links you want to capture? Ideally with a bit of context so folks can get an idea of what structural selectors to try.

Comment: @krivard `<div class="exhibition-section content-wrapper">
  <hr/>
  <section id="exhibition-secondary" class="exhibition__secondary-text grid">
    <div class="col col--12">
      <h2>2012 Biennial Artists</h2><p><a class="btn" href="/exhibitions/2012-biennial/on-view">On view by floor</a></p><p class="paragraph-column--three"><br></p><p class="paragraph-column--three">Kai Althoff<br><a href="/exhibitions/2012-biennial/Thom-Andersen">Thom Andersen<br></a><a href="/exhibitions/2012-biennial/Charles-Atlas">Charles Atlas</a><br> ` each url containing "/2012-biennial/" to capture and parse